# PHP Errors after Ajax Return (codeigniter framework)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xcode, e-commerce

I am working on a custom ecommerce website. If you go to the following link you can view my issue live.

[custom ecommerce site »](http://faithpointdallas.com/ecom/category/view/choir-stoles)

(username: alex, password: superman)

My problem is that when you click add to cart, my jquery ajax post works great and your item is added to the cart. However, if you first filter by price, THEN try and add to cart, I get a php error. Any ideas why this would be happening...

I'm not super farmiliar with ajax, this is my first super intense ajax project so it may just be something simple like a problem i had earlier where someone introduced me to the live() function in jQuery.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are you doing in models/admin_model.php Line Number: 667 ? if you can put the PHP method and jQuery call.

Comment: What did you not understand from googling `undefined offset php`? Or did you not go that far? It would seem that there's an empty array you're trying to access, and that array isn't being populated because some value being passed to the server is either `null || undefined || 0`.

Comment: I can tell you for sure that your `.live` events are not working when you have filtered your data. Clicking on a filtered item results in following its HREF value and no ajax call is made. Need your code please!

Comment: @DavidBarker You just turned a light on in my head and everythings working fine now.

I had: $('.addToCartButton').live("click", function(event) {

rather than: $('a.addToCartButton').live("click", function(event) {

specifying that it was the "a" element with that class fixed it.

Comment: To future proof you, stop using .live (it was actually deprecated some time back). Try `.on` instead. Similar syntax but you bind to a lower level elemeent. `$(document).on('click', 'a.addToCartButton', function(e){...});`

Comment: Yeah I read about that earlier and I was about to change my functions to use that. Thanks for the help. I'm moving along in the project again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so your normal "Add to cart" button works with AJAX. So far so good.

What you are missing is that when you are filtering by price, you are (most probably) removing all the items from the list, and adding back only those which meet the price criteria. So far so good too!

After the filtered items are added back, however, you don't re-initialize the JavaScript bindings on the "Add to cart" buttons.

Wherever you are doing something like:

```
jQuery('.add-to-cart').bind('click', function(){
  // show lightbox and do some stuff here
}
```

You need to either call this method / function again, after the filtering is done, or a simpler solution would be to bind the events using `live`:

```
jQuery('.add-to-cart').live('click', function(){
  // do the same stuff as above
}
```

Please note that these pieces of code are only an example, I didn't actually take your code.